# Using html5 localstorage instead of cookies with passport.js

Tags: oauth, local-storage, passport.js, node-webkit, passport-twitter

Is there any way to use localstorage instead of cookies when dealing with passport.js oauth implementations (such as google, twitter or facebook) for persistence login?

The reason is quite simple: you can't use cookies in native apps wrappers like node-webkit or atom shell.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer?